# Adding a new venue in Events Calendar using Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm using webhooks as documented here: https://docs.gravityforms.com/calendar-events-webhooks-addon-wp-restapi/ to add a new event to the Modern Tribe Events Calendar using Gravity Forms.

I have a radio field for the Venues which is auto populated using the Gravity Wiz 'Populate Anything' add on which works really well and saves to the newly created event but I want to add the option to add a new venue in the form too (and for this to be saved as a Venue Post and also be related to the newly created event).

I have access to another add on from Gravity Wiz called Nested Forms, which I can use to create the new Venue (also using the Advanced Post Creation add on from Gravity Forms) but I can't work out the function I need to write to get this saved alongside the newly created Event.

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to add the following to your functions.php to run the API for your nested form:

add_filter( 'gpnf_enable_feed_processing_setting', '__return_true' );

See more info here:
https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/#feed-processing

Comment: Thanks Rochelle, I should have mentioned that the nested form (venue creation) is working great and yes I have set the nested form feed to process on the submission of the nested form - not the parent. What I can't do is then get the newly created venue ID to map it to a field in the parent OR use this ID in a gf hook after submission.

Comment: I may not totally understand but would the following work...The form allows you to pick from a list of populated venue posts. If the venue isn't listed, could you add a checkbox that says "create new venue"? Then add conditional logic fields that appear for this venue. After submission, if "create new venue" checkbox is checked, create a venue post programmatically based on these new fields? After the post creation, you can add a hook that will update the original form entry with the new post id into the original dropdown field.  If my description is right, I can give you some sample code.

Comment: Yes that is exactly it! And I can do everything up to: "After the post creation, you can add a hook that will update the original form entry with the new post id into the original dropdown field. If my description is right, I can give you some sample code.". It's this part where I'm getting stuck, retrieving the newly created post's ID and updating the entry. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
//after submission
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_453', 'update_venue', 10, 2 );//replace 453 with gravity form id
function update_venue($entry, $form ){
   if($entry['1.1'] !== 'Yes'){//replace 1.1 with the field number of the "create new venue?" question. Replace Yes with whatever your checkbox value is
      return;
   }else{
      // Create post object
      $venue_post = array(
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $entry['4'] ),//replace 4 with field id of venue name
        'post_content'  => $entry['5'],//replace 5 with field id with venue description
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_category' => array( 25,68 ) //replace 25 and 68 with category ids if there are any
      );
       
      $venue_ID = wp_insert_post( $venue_post );
      $entry['3'] = $venue_ID;//replace 3 with number of the dropdown venue field
      $result = GFAPI::update_entry( $entry );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rochelle. I've gone a slightly different route because the advanced custom post creation add on was doing the hard work to add the venue as a new post. Even though it's a different solution I wouldn't have got there without your help so thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

function pre_submission_handler( $form ) {
$venueId = rgpost( 'input_25' );

```
$created_posts = gform_get_meta( $venueId, 'gravityformsadvancedpostcreation_post_id' );

if (!empty($created_posts)) {

    foreach ( $created_posts as $post ) {
        $post_id = $post['post_id'];
    }

    $_POST['input_24'] = $post_id;
}
```

}

Solved by mapping one field to another in the end.